# How to get repeated tag values from an xml in string format (Java)

Tags: java, xml, string

I Have an xml in this format:

```
<Container1>
<Description>one</Description>
</Container1>
<Container2>
<Description>Two</Description>
</Container2>
```

Am reading this xml to a String.(There is a reason why I cant parse the xml directly)
Now from that String I need to take the values of all Description tags to a List
Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: Can't you parse that string *directly* or can't you parse that string *at all*? Because if you can parse it, that's what you should do. And then you can use XPath: `//Description`. Very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are receiving the xml ,you can parse it and the use XPath to extract the necessary information. Please note that you need to pass the valid xml to `builder#parse` (I wrapped your xml in root element).

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class XPathExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        String s = "<root>\n" +
                "<Container1>\n" +
                "<Description>one</Description>\n" +
                "</Container1>\n" +
                "<Container2>\n" +
                "<Description>Two</Description>\n" +
                "</Container2>\n" +
                "</root>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression descriptionExpr = xpath.compile("//Description/text()");
        Object result = descriptionExpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
one
Two
```